# Trying to reformat a string to a specific date format

Tags: ios, swift3, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a string that is a date in this format `03/02/2017`

I would like to display it like this `Mar 2, 2017`

I've been trying to get this formatter to work, but it keeps giving me nil, and I don't think I'm setting it in the correct format.

```
// convert saved date from string
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy" //Your date format
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: '03/02/2017')
print("\(date) save date") // nil
historyEntry.date = date as NSDate?
```

Answer (score 2):

is not in

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
```

it is in

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
```

for full output

```
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

     // iinitiallly set the date format based on your date 
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy" //Your date format

    // convert the string to date , but date is not the proper format , so dont worry about this
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "03/02/2017")

    // again reassign what the output you need set the date format
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd, yyyy" // if you need the same as Mar 2, 2017 then use  "MMM d, yyyy"

      // finally convert your date to string
     let myStringafd = dateFormatter.string(from: date!)
    print("\(myStringafd) save date")
```

**output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
let dateString = "03/02/2017"
        let df = DateFormatter()
        df.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"  // this dateformat should be your current string's date format
        df.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC-05:00") // if there is timezone you want to set
        if let date = df.date(from: dateString) {
            df.dateFormat = "MMM dd, yyyy" // This dateformat is that you want as result
            let stringFromDate = df.string(from: date)
            cell.lblDate.text = stringFromDate
        }
```